# How to print a running count within a Gaussian loop

Tags: python

I have a script which is running a certain function 100000 times before providing my output file. This takes about 15 minutes to run on my machine and just staring at the blank line in the terminal is tedious. I was wondering if it is possible to print which n/100000 it is up to, continually rolling down the screen while the code is running, so that I have a continual count and know where it is up to.

The pertinent code is:

```
#Import statements

NDENSITIES = 100000
densities = np.random.normal(-100, 50 NDENSITIES)
results = np.zeros(shape=n, NDENSITIES))
for density in range(0, NDENSITIES):
    model = Prism(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000, 2000, 2500, {'density': densities[density]})
    data = np.array(prism.potential(x, y, z, [model]))
    results[:,density] = data
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Why is this being downvoted? How is what I've asked any different to any other question on this site?

Comment: IMHO it would be better to [log](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) it at `debug` level instead of printing to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_every = 1000
for density in range(0, NDENSITIES):
    if density % print_every == 0:
        print 'finished %s iterations' % density
    model = Prism(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000, 2000, 2500, {'density': densities[density]}
```

This code will print the number of iterations finished every `print_every`